# How do i validate all countries phone number with php

Tags: php

Is there any way to validate all countries phone number with php

Comment: Given a suitable dataset for comparison, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement this by using preg_match, i dont think any automatic validation exist

By using a database for storing formats and then checking those with entered phonenumber

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

eg.,

```
<?php
// The "i" after the pattern delimiter indicates a case-insensitive search
if (preg_match("/php/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
?>
```

see this 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

Take the information about country phone number starting codes from:
 http://www.international-dialing-codes.net/

insert into database, create array, make while cycle where it will get information from DB, 
then create foreach..
something like that..